How to detect when a dynamically changing <embed> src finished loading?
I am using JavaScript to load dynamic PDF content into an <embed> element:


document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  document.querySelector('embed').src = 'https://example.com/';
});
<div id="embed-container">
  <embed>
</div>
<button>Load Embed Content</button>



How can I detect when it finished loading? You can see in the devtools that when the button is clicked, there's a pending GET request to that URL. In my case it takes a few seconds to load so I want to display a loading animation and once it finished pending and I get 200 then show the <embed> (Instead of displaying a blank page for a few seconds)

You can hide the element with display: none and use the load event to make it visible once the content has been loaded.


const emb = document.querySelector('embed');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener("click", () =>  emb.src = 'https://example.com/');
emb.addEventListener('load', () => emb.style.display = 'block');
embed {display: "none";}
<div id="embed-container">
  <embed>
</div>
<button>Load Embed Content</button>




You can create a load event for the embed during the button click and add a loader too:


let embedContainer = document.querySelector("#embed-container");
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  embedContainer.classList.add("loading");
  let embed = embedContainer.querySelector('embed');
  embed.src = 'https://example.com/';
  embed.addEventListener("load", function() {
      embedContainer.classList.remove("loading");
      embedContainer.classList.add("loaded");
  });
});
#embed-container > embed {
    display: none;
}

#embed-container > .placeholder {
    display: none;
}

#embed-container.loading > .placeholder {
    display: block;
    width: 302px;
    height: 152px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.placeholder img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#embed-container.loaded > .placeholder {
    display: none;
}

#embed-container.loaded > embed {
    display: block;
}
<div id="embed-container">
  <embed>
  <div class="placeholder">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif">
  </div>
</div>
<button>Load Embed Content</button>



